# Can't seem to get this trigger 100% coverage. Any Ideas?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

Can't seem to get above 65% test coverage, I have marked where I am lacked coverage as far as I can tell it should cover this area but I am clearly missing something, any ideas?

**RelatedContactClass**

```
public class RelatedContantClass {
public static void addRelatedContact (List <Lead> leadsFromTrigger) {

    //Create List for Opportunities to be updated from
    list <Opportunity> opportunityUpdates = new list <Opportunity> ();

    //For each Lead in the Trigger
    for (Lead currentLead : leadsFromTrigger){

        //Check if they have been converted
        if (currentLead.IsConverted == TRUE){

            //Check if the Lead Conversion included an Opportunity, then assign the contact to the Opportunity as Opportunity Contact Role Records
            if (currentLead.convertedOpportunityId != NULL) {

                list <Lead_Contact_Connector__c> LeadContactList = new list <Lead_Contact_Connector__c> ([Select Related_Contact__c, Contact_Role__c, Lead__c From Lead_Contact_Connector__c where Lead__c = :currentLead.Id]); 
                    list <OpportunityContactRole> ContactRoleNew = new list <OpportunityContactRole> ();
                        for (Lead_Contact_Connector__c CurrentContact: LeadContactList){
                            OpportunityContactRole OppCon = new OpportunityContactRole(); // << No coverage
                            OppCon.ContactId = CurrentContact.Related_Contact__c;  // << No coverage
                            OppCon.OpportunityId = currentLead.convertedOpportunityId;  // << No coverage
                            OppCon.Role = CurrentContact.Contact_Role__c;  // << No coverage
                            ContactRoleNew.add(OppCon);  // << No coverage
                }

                insert ContactRoleNew;

            }

        }

    }}}
```

**RelatedContactClassTest**

```
@isTest
private class RelatedContactClassTest {

static testMethod void testCreateContactFromCandidate() {

    //Set up basic testing data.

   //Create a single Account for converting with an Opportunity
    Account aAccount = new Account (
        Name = 'First Test');

   //Create a single Contact for converting with an Opportunity
    Contact aContact = new Contact (
        FirstName = 'First Test',
        LastName = 'Lead',
        AccountId = aAccount.Id);

    //Create a single Lead for converting with an Opportunity
    Lead aLead = new Lead (
        FirstName = 'First Test',
        LastName = 'Lead',
        Company = 'Test Company X',
        Status = 'New',
        LeadSource = 'Web');

  //create opportunity 
  Opportunity aOpp = new Opportunity(
    Name='Test Opp'
  );
  //Create a single Related Contact for converting with an Opportunity
    Lead_Contact_Connector__c aRelatedContact = new Lead_Contact_Connector__c(
        Lead__c  = aLead.Id,
        Contact_Role__c = 'Authorised Contact',
        Related_Contact__c = aContact.Id);


   //Create a single Lead for converting without an Opportunity
        Lead bLead = new Lead (
        FirstName = 'Second Test',
        LastName = 'Lead - No Opportunity',
        Company = 'Test Company Y',
        Status = 'New',
        LeadSource = 'Web');

   //Create a single Account for converting with an Opportunity
    Account bAccount = new Account (
        Name = 'First Test');

   //Create a single Contact for converting with an Opportunity
    Contact bContact = new Contact (
        FirstName = 'First Test',
        LastName = 'Lead',
        AccountId = bAccount.Id);

  //Create a single Related Contact for converting with an Opportunity
    Lead_Contact_Connector__c bRelatedContact = new Lead_Contact_Connector__c(
        Lead__c  = bLead.Id,
        Contact_Role__c = 'Authorised Contact',
        Related_Contact__c = bContact.Id);            

    // Create 210 Leads for Converting with Opportunities
    List <Lead> leadList = new List <Lead> ();
    List <Account> AccountList = new List <Account> ();
    List <Contact> ContactList = new List <Contact> ();
    List <Lead_Contact_Connector__c> LCCList = new List <Lead_Contact_Connector__c> ();


    //Loop to create 210 Leads

    For (Integer i=0; i < 210; i++) {
        Account currentAccount = new Account ();
        currentAccount.Name = 'Test ' + i;            

        Contact currentContact = new Contact ();
        currentContact.FirstName = 'Test ' + i;
        currentContact.LastName = 'Lead';
        currentContact.AccountId = currentAccount.Id;
        ContactList.add(currentContact);


        Lead currentLead = new Lead ();
        currentLead.FirstName = 'Test ' + i;
        currentLead.LastName = 'Lead';
        currentLead.Company = 'Test Company ' + i;
        currentLead.Status = 'New';
        currentLead.LeadSource = 'Web';

        Lead_Contact_Connector__c relatedContactLarge = new Lead_Contact_Connector__c ();
        relatedContactLarge.Lead__c = currentLead.Id;
        relatedContactLarge.Contact_Role__c = 'Authorised Contact';
        relatedContactLarge.Related_Contact__c = currentContact.Id;

        LCCList.add(relatedContactLarge);
        leadList.add(currentLead);
        AccountList.add(currentAccount);
        }

    //Set the converted Lead Status as a Lead Status that exists in the org.
  LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];

    //_______________________________________________

    //Create each of the single leads and multi leads

    system.debug('single Lead: ' + aLead.FirstName + aLead.LastName);
    insert aLead;

    system.debug('single Lead: ' + bLead.FirstName + bLead.LastName);
    insert bLead;

    system.debug(leadList);
    database.insert(leadList);
    database.insert(LCCList);
    database.insert(ContactList);
    database.insert(AccountList);


    //_______________________________________________

    //Carry out the processes and testing logic

    //Test1
    //Verify that the single Lead converts with anis the converted Contact.
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(aLead.id);
        //This selects this first converted lead status possible.
    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
    lc.setOpportunityName('Test Opp 1');
        //This tests that the Lead conversion was successful.

    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);        
    System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
    system.debug(lcr.isSuccess());


    }
}
```

Comment: Just a friendly reminder that SOQL inside of a loop is a very bad idea. (In `RelatedContantClass ` on your line starting with `list <Lead_Contact_Connector__c> LeadContactList...`

Comment: I don't see any `assert` statements. Why don't you try writing a `System.assert(LeadContactList.size() != 0);`, and see if the test class still passes? If not, you'll likely need to re-approach your test class.

Comment: @battery.cord there is one assertion towards the very end of OP's test class, but I do agree that additional assertions are in order here.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I added the System.assert(LeadContactList.size() != 0); but still only getting 63% code coverage I have tried altering the code but keep dropping not sure where to go

Comment: @Nebbyyy I see that you forgot to `insert bRelatedContact;` which is most likely your problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox where do you mean specifically bit confused by the comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually "saving" any of those records you're creating new the top of your unit test. it's not enough to say, for example, `Account anAccount = new Account(Name='Test');`, you have to then follow it up with `insert anAccount;`. Your entire test is basically failing because you're not inserting data into the database.

Generally speaking, when you create a unit test, it should probably go a lot like this:

- Create parent record
- Insert parent record
- Create child record
- Insert child record
- Create grand-child record
- Insert grand-child record
- ... etc ...

Here's a fixed version of the top half of your code:

```
//Create a single Account for converting with an Opportunity
Account aAccount = new Account (
    Name = 'First Test');
insert aAccount;

//Create a single Contact for converting with an Opportunity
Contact aContact = new Contact (
    FirstName = 'First Test',
    LastName = 'Lead',
    AccountId = aAccount.Id);

insert aContact;

//Create a single Lead for converting with an Opportunity
Lead aLead = new Lead (
    FirstName = 'First Test',
    LastName = 'Lead',
    Company = 'Test Company X',
    Status = 'New',
    LeadSource = 'Web');
insert aLead;

//create opportunity 
Opportunity aOpp = new Opportunity(
    Name='Test Opp'
);
insert aOpp;

//Create a single Related Contact for converting with an Opportunity
Lead_Contact_Connector__c aRelatedContact = new Lead_Contact_Connector__c(
    Lead__c  = aLead.Id,
    Contact_Role__c = 'Authorised Contact',
    Related_Contact__c = aContact.Id);
insert aRelatedContact;

//Create a single Lead for converting without an Opportunity
Lead bLead = new Lead (
    FirstName = 'Second Test',
    LastName = 'Lead - No Opportunity',
    Company = 'Test Company Y',
    Status = 'New',
    LeadSource = 'Web');
insert bLead;

//Create a single Account for converting with an Opportunity
Account bAccount = new Account (
    Name = 'First Test');
insert bAccount;

//Create a single Contact for converting with an Opportunity
Contact bContact = new Contact (
    FirstName = 'First Test',
    LastName = 'Lead',
    AccountId = bAccount.Id);
insert bContact;

//Create a single Related Contact for converting with an Opportunity
Lead_Contact_Connector__c bRelatedContact = new Lead_Contact_Connector__c(
    Lead__c  = bLead.Id,
    Contact_Role__c = 'Authorised Contact',
    Related_Contact__c = bContact.Id);            
insert bRelatedContact;
```

As you can see, I take turns alternating between creating records in memory (`new Account(...)`) and then inserting them.

Comment: somehow I now have 28% test coverage, im so confused :(

Comment: @Nebbyyy You'll want to check the test's logs. On the Tests tab in the developer console, double-click the test's results to see the errors.

Comment: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [StageName, CloseDate]: [StageName, CloseDate],

Comment: its referencing line 150 which is the test 1

Comment: @Nebbyyy The error means that `aOpp` is missing those fields. I didn't check for required fields, it was meant to be illustrative.